# Bash While...Do Loop With Awk - Pass Parameters Into User-Defined Awk Function

Tags: bash, awk

I am using `find` with a bash loop to execute `awk` over and over. The plan is to replace a given string (`STRINGER` in this post) with the basename of the input file and a random string. That is, when the loop comes to `input.txt`, it replaces `STRINGER` each time with `input-8dsA`.

```
var=1
find . -type f -name '*.txt'| while read F
do
awk -vff="$F" -i inplace 'function rndm(cmd, line, r, file) {
    "basename $ff | sed 's/\.vue//g'" | getline slug ## THIS is my problem

    cmd = "tr -dc \047[:alnum:]\047 </dev/urandom | head -c4" # Generate a 4-character string
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0)
        r = slug "-" line ## I want the basename then dash then random characters (basename-XXXX)
        close(cmd)
        return r
}
{
    sub(/STRINGER/, rndm()) ## Do the write.
}' ${F}
((var+=1))
done
```

When I run this, I get: `basename: missing operand Try 'basename --help' for more information.`, which tells me that there is an empty variable being placed in for `$ff` when I use the `basename` command to get the actual filename.

This does work, but does NOT incorporate the filename (I have removed the `basename` stuff):

```
var=1
find . -type f -name '*.txt'| while read F
do
awk -vff="$F" -i inplace 'function rndm(cmd, line, r, file) {
    cmd = "tr -dc \047[:alnum:]\047 </dev/urandom | head -c4" # Generate a 4-character string
    if ( (cmd | getline line) > 0)
        r = line ## I want the basename of the ff input file, here
        close(cmd)
        return r
}
{
    sub(/STRINGER/, rndm()) ## Do the write.
}' ${F}
((var+=1))
done
```

In a list of `.txt` files that `find` found, replace `STRINGER` with the basename of the input file followed by a `-` followed by a 4-character random string.

What do I need to do in order to get the `$F` bash variable from a big while...do loop into a user-defined `awk` function? I thought that `-v ff="$F"` would let me use `$ff`, but that does not appear to be the case.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like this might be what you're trying to do but without sample input/output to test with it's just a guess:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec \
awk -i inplace '
    BEGIN {
        srand()
        alnumChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"
        numAlnums  = length(alnumChars)
        numRands   = 4
    }
    FNR == 1 {
        basename = FILENAME
        sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",basename)
    
        randStr = ""
        for (i=1; i<=numRands; i++) {
            randStr = randStr substr(alnumChars, int(1 + rand()*numAlnums), 1)
        }
    
        repl = basename "-" randStr
    }
    {
       gsub(/STRINGER/,repl)
       print
    }
}' {} +
```

The above requires GNU awk (for `-i inplace`).

Comment: does the `-i inplace` work with multiple input files?

Comment: @Fravadona yes, it does. That was a big driver for getting the gawk guys to provide it, so it could be used with `find` this way.

Comment: Ed, what's the call on `{}` and not `'{}'`. My understanding was quoting was needed to protect against whitespace, etc.. in the filename. Have I been unnecessarily quoting `{}` in `-exec` and `-execdir`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've never come across `{}` quoted and I just tried `find . -type f -exec awk '{print FILENAME, $0}' {} +` on a directory containing file names with spaces and `$`s with no problem. The POSIX standard https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html doesn't say they must be quoted and doesn't quote it in  their examples but the Linux man page https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html says that they must be quoted and shows it quoted in the examples section so - I'd guess that man page is wrong and may be why you think quoting is necessary?

Comment: Try cd-ing to an empty directory then `echo 1 > 'a b'; echo 2 > '$HOME'` then `find . -type f -exec ls {} +` and it'll output `'./$HOME'  './a b'` - no issues with the file names.